# Faulting module name: PresentationFramework.ni.dll

Tags: wpf, windows, exception

An application i wrote crashes and in the event viewer i found the following :

> Faulting module name: PresentationFramework.ni.dll, version:
>   4.0.30319.233, time stamp: 0x4d930fa2 Exception code: 0xc00000fd

couple of questions:

1. what is the PresentationFramework.ni.dll?
2. how can i know if this exception is caused by something wrong in my application or something    unrelated?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PresentationFramework.ni.dll is the ngen-ed version of the PresentationFramework assembly, a key assembly for WPF.

Exception code 0xc00000fd means StackoverflowException.  A pretty notorious exception for which this site is named that instantly terminates your application with little to look at.  It is always caused by a programming bug.  You'll need to debug your app.

Answer (score 3):

That assembly is part of .NET Framework. Your need to know the exception stack trace. You might try to capture a crash dump and analyze.