# Application crash with faulty module 'PresentationFramework.ni.dll'

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Faulting module name: PresentationFramework.ni.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396688/faulting-module-name-presentationframework-ni-dll)

I have a customer where my application crashes from time to time. I have now found the fallowing entry in the windows eventlog:

> ```
> Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: proconact.exe, Version: 1.0.0.1359, Zeitstempel: 0x5108214a
> Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: PresentationFramework.ni.dll, Version: 4.0.30319.550, Zeitstempel: 0x4f17f745
> Ausnahmecode: 0xc00000fd
> Fehleroffset: 0x002eed3b
> ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0xb60
> Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01cdfecc60631116
> Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\proconact_sck\proconact.exe
> Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationFramewo#\d4417b9c53da6268abb1c7c2154ab37d\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
> Berichtskennung: e9c9fefe-6acb-11e2-b3e2-18a9051d2feb
> ```

I am wondering me about the name of the faulty module 'PresentationFramework.ni.dll'

Can someone help me, what can be the reason for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396688/faulting-module-name-presentationframework-ni-dll

Comment: Can you check whether there is an additional entry in the event log containing the stack trace?

Comment: @0xA3 - I find no stacktrace. But I am wondering me, why it would not call my AppDomainExceptionHandler which I have registered like AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomainUnhandledException;

Comment: @t.kehl: As described in the question linked in the first comment, your error is due to a StackOverflowException. This is a non-recoverable exception, i.e. your program quits immediately and no further code (like the exception handler) is executed.

Comment: @0xA3 - Is there any way to get out the stacktrace or some more information where this exception occurs?

Comment: @t.kehl: Apparently, the stacktrace of SOE is not logged to the event log. You can try using adplus (`adplus -hang -pn <process name> -o <dump file>`) and windbg as described here to retrieve a stacktrace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817662%28pandp.10%29.aspx